# How do you add flair to facebook as a sidebar widget?

Tags: support, flair, facebook

I joined the StackOverflow Facebook group, but I didn't see any info on how to do this.

Comment: still no answer?

Comment: doesnt look like it. there was a facebook app but its gone now. http://apps.facebook.com/stackoverflow_badge/